# Oracle SQL regex and column splitting

Tags: sql, regex, oracle

I'm working with Oracle and JDBC to set up a database with a list of movies. The fields that load are MovieId, MovieTitle, and Genre. 
Format ex:

```
MovieId       MovieTitle             Genre
1            Toy Story (1997)      Animated
```

Now I need to split my MovieTitle to list the year 1997 in a separate column called "Year". I got it to work earlier using this:

```
SELECT SUBSTR(Movies.MovieTitle, 1, INSTR(Movies.MovieTitle, '(')-1) AS MovieTitle,
   SUBSTR(Movies.MovieTitle, INSTR(Movies.MovieTitle, ')')) AS Year
 FROM MOVIES;
```

However that is no good, because some of my movies have parenthesis in their title. So I believe I need to use regex, however I can't get it to work. Here is what I have been playing around with:

```
 WITH TEST AS
(SELECT MovieTitle FROM Movies)
SELECT REGEXP_SUBSTR(Movies.MovieTitle, '^\(\d{4}\)$', 1, 1) MovieTitle,
   REGEXP_SUBSTR(Movies.MovieTitle, '^\(\d{4}\)$', 1, 2) Year
FROM Movies;
```

All that gives me is two null columns for all my movies. Am I on the right track with this or way off? Another concern is that I want this to be an update on my original Movies table, not a new query or table of its own. Thanks for any suggestions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that `^` is the start of string anchor (it matches the start of string position) and `$` matches the end of string position. `^\(\d{4}\)$` matches a string like `(1234)`, and there is no point setting the start position or number of match then since you require the whole string to match the pattern.

You may use

```
REGEXP_SUBSTR(Movies.MovieTitle, '\((\d{4})\)', 1, 1, NULL, 1)
```

It will extract the first 4-digit sequence that is enclosed with `(` and `)`.

**Details**:

- `\(` -  a literal `(`
- `(\d{4})` - Group 1 (referred to with the last `1` argument to the `REGEXP_SUBSTR`) capturing exactly 4 consecutive digits
- `\)` - a literal `)`.

See the [online demo](http://rextester.com/LEBH29044).

Comment: Great! That definitely helps with extracting the numbers, but how do I get a separate column in my movies table?

Comment: @Polyphase29: That is something not related to regex already. I think you need to have that column already, and just insert the extracted value into it.

Comment: So that SQL works when I run it on my database in SQL Developer, however I'm trying to execute it using my Java code and it keeps confusing me with wanting to do a java escape sequence that I think it's messing up my SQL statement. Through some searches I thought changing my regex to '\\\\((\\\\d{4})\\\\)' would fix it, but it just results in null each time. Any ideas on what I can update to make it work?

Comment: @Polyphase29: You may avoid using backslashes by enclosing literal parentheses into `[...]` and change `\d` into `[0-9]`: `[(]([0-9]{4})[)]`

Comment: Sorry - ONE last question, promise. Now I'm trying to REMOVE the Year from my MovieTitle column. I almost have it, but my result is giving me ex: Toy Story (). I can't seem to get rid of the extra () there. Here was my attempt:
    UPDATE Movies
     SET MovieTitle = REPLACE(MovieTitle, 
    REGEXP_SUBSTR(Movies.MovieTitle, '([(][0-9]{4}[)])', 1, 1, NULL, 1), '');

Comment: Why not use a `REGEXP_REPLACE` directly? See [this online demo](http://rextester.com/DDXR90783).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/144999/discussion-between-polyphase29-and-wiktor-stribizew).